# No local packages or working download links found for python_version (thought it exists)

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install/setup this git repo:
https://github.com/xiahongze/pdf_annot

I am getting this error:

```
> python setup.py install
:
:
Installed e:\work\projs\scraping\scan_pdfs\scanpdfs\lib\site-packages\pdf_annot-0.1.0-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pdf-annot==0.1.0
Searching for python_version>=3.7
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/python_version/
No local packages or working download links found for python_version>=3.7
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('python_version>=3.7')
```

My python version is:

```
> python --version
Python 3.7.6
```

Same issue happens with `pip install`. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's is](https://github.com/xiahongze/pdf_annot/blob/8552ce54550a106bbc93b906b749adc333b7924f/setup.py#L17) a bug in `setup.py`. This is how it must be written:

```
python_requires='>=3.7',
install_requires=[
    'PyMuPDF>=1.16'
],
```

Let's see. [`pdf-annot`](https://pypi.org/project/pdf-annot/#history), the only release version 0.1 was in 2019. [Not even a single bug report](https://github.com/xiahongze/pdf_annot/issues). The package seems unused, broken and abandoned.

You can try to send a pull request to fix it but I suspect it will be stuck. Perhaps the best course of action for you is to fork the repository, fix it and install from your fork.

PS. Well, there is a package [`python-version`](https://pypi.org/project/python_version/#history) with a single release version 0.2. Certainly not a dependency for this package.

Answer (score -1):

Please sure the network is connected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).